# Spark job hangs on worker with CPU pegged at 100%

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

Occasionally my Spark job seems to hang indefinitely on a worker whose CPU seems to be at 100% - I notice this while repeatedly running top.

```
Tasks: 288 total,   1 running, 287 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 25157609+total, 11158460+free, 55086460 used, 84905024 
buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 19393204+avail Mem

PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ 
COMMAND
71167 XXXX      20   0  0.213t 0.049t  28576 S 100.0 20.8 231:58.71 
java
```

I'm running PySpark on a Spark standalone cluster and it hangs on a `reduceByKey` operation that would normally take seconds to complete. Whenever this happens its on a single worker, and I notice that the Locality Level is ANY. I normally just reboot the EC2 instance (working on AWS) and the job then gets allocated to another worker(s) and the job eventually succeeds. I'm wondering what are my options for a more sustainable fix. Would it be a switch to YARN to identify and kill off such workers ? I've avoided YARN so far because of the need to install HDFS given that my pipeline persists directly to S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't let any of your workers get to 100% CPU.

If you used Yarn you could have limiting the number of cores you allow the job to use.

Another option will be to use cgroups on the workers to limit the CPU usage.

Comment: But would YARN help me identify such workers whose CPU seems pegged for a long time and kill them so the tasks get re-assigned in order for the job  to proceed ?

Comment: If you use Yarn and/or cgroups you won't get to the unfortunate situation of having a worker reach 100% CPU in the first place. Note, that If you have other process running on the worker, Yarn by itself won't help you and you will also need cgroups.